# Moving through a list items one by one in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey I am pretty new to python and I suppose this could be a very basic question. I searched through a forum but I couldn't find a matching question as of mine.

I have a list of strings:

```
target = ('off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on')
```

Now I want to move through the items of the list one by one every time I run the code:

```
for current_target in target:
print(current_target)
```

However, the for loop runs through all the items in one go. What I want is that every time I run the code it should move to the next item in the list.

Can anyone please help me solve this?

Thanks
Vatsal

EDIT: The OP explanation of the problem in the  comments is :

"For instance I wrote a code that could will print a single item from of a list. When I again run that code it'll print the next item. So first it should print the item with index 0 then when I re-run the code it should print the item with the index 1 thus so on and so forth till the end of the list."

Please read this before answering.

Comment: What, **exactly** do you mean by "every time I run the code"?

Comment: For instance I wrote a code that could will print a single item from of a list. When I again run that code it'll print the next item. So first it should print the item with index 0 then when I re-run the code it should print the item with the index 1 thus so on and so forth till the end of the list.

Comment: Then you don't need a *list*. Lists live in volatile memory, you need some way to *store* the data. This could be as simple as a text-file, or as complex as a database, but you can't do what you are trying to do by simply defining a list. The program has no memory of the "last time it was run", **you have to do that**.

Comment: As an alternative, maybe add an input statement just before or just after your print statement. Then, run the program once and when you're ready for the next target, just hit enter on your keyboard.

Comment: have a look at my code @Vatsal

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [pop()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/array.html#array.array.pop) to remove items from a copy of the array one by one (preserving the original array in case you need it later). This only works in memory as noted in the comments.

```
copy_target = array(target)
a = copy_target.pop(0) # Returns 'off'
b = copy_target.pop(0) # Returns the next 'off'
```

Answer (score 1):

Very basic example of persistent data.

Using a text editor, create a file named e.g. 'list.json' with the desired list of strings:

```
["off", "off", "off", "on", "off", "on", "off", "off", "off", "on", "on", "off", "off", "on", "off", "off", "on", "off", "off", "on"]
```

Then every time you run this program, it reads the whole list from the file, prints the first element and saves the rest back to the file. After repeated invocations the list will be consumed and a new one should be prepared.

```
import json
FILE='list.json'    # should be full path 

with open(FILE) as f:
    lst = json.load(f)
if lst:
    print(lst[0])
    with open(FILE,"w") as f:
        json.dump(lst[1:], f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `generator`s?

For example:

```
target = ('off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on')

def nextitem(items):
    yield from items

loopover = nextitem(target)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(loopover))
    except StopIteration:
        print('reached end of list')
        break
```

which prints ...

```
off
off
off
on
off
on
off
off
off
on
on
off
off
on
off
off
on
off
off
on
reached end of list
```

The *generator* is freezing the status and each invocation with `next` gives you the next value. You can keep the generator stored in a data structure, run some other code and recall the *generator* and use the *next* value.

With a list you can obviously do directly the same by using `loopover = iter(target)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file to store the reference of execution. Start with 0 as the content and increment for each execution.Once the list is exhausted reset the content to 0

```
target = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'tweleve')

with open("1.txt","r") as f:
    num = int(f.read())
    print target[num]

with open("1.txt","w") as f:
    if num >= len(target)-1:
        f.write("0")
    else:
        f.write(str(num+1))
```

file:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat 1.txt
0
```